# R: Why is this not considered a valid 'if' condition?

Tags: r

I want to build a function that first verifies that the entered vector contains only the three characters `"p", "s", "r"` (in any number or order).
I tried various iterations of:

```
  if (any (vec) != c("r", "p", "s")) {stop ("Inputs have to be rock, paper and scissors.")}
```

Like separating the conditions with `|` but even just having the condition for one letter, returns:

```
Error in if (any(vec) != c("r", "p", "s")) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In any(vec) : coercing argument of type 'character' to logical
2: In if (any(vec) != c("r", "p", "s")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Love to figure out why R is not considering this as a legit condition with TRUE/FALSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the condition returns a logical vector of length greater than 1, and `if/else` works with length of 1.  Change the condition to something like below and it would work

```
if(!any(vec %in% c("r", "p", "s"))) {
      stop ("Inputs have to be rock, paper and scissors.")}
#Error: Inputs have to be rock, paper and scissors.
```

#### data

```
vec <- c("a", "b")
```

Comment: So simple yet I never even though of it. Thank you!

Comment: logic looks weird. Should it be `all` instead of `any`?

Comment: @dww You can use some combinations with `all`, `any` etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

In your if statement, you're comparing `any(vec)` to the character vector `c("r", "p", "s")`. It looks like you intended to use the `any` function after the comparison (i.e. just watch your brackets). Something like this is an easy fix and is probably what you intended:

```
if (any (vec != c("r", "p", "s"))) {stop ("Inputs have to be rock, paper and scissors.")}
```

**Looking at the error message:**

`any` is a function which takes logical (i.e. `TRUE` or `FALSE`) input, and returns logical output (it returns `TRUE` if any of the elements of the input vector are `TRUE`, otherwise `FALSE`).

The first warning message is because `vec` is character, but since R expects a logical input for `any`, it tries to turn (or coerce) your character vector into a logical vector (equivalent to doing `any(as.logical(vec))`). This coercion from character to logical produces `NA`, since there's no natural way of doing this.

After your first warning, R has evaluated `any(vec)`, and you next evaluates `NA != c("r", "p", "s")`. This produces `NA NA NA`, and an `if` statement expects logical input of length 1; this is where your second warning comes in - R tells your that it'll only look at the first of the three elements.

The error is produced because you end up with `if(NA)` and `NA` isn't `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and can't be coerced into either. Roughly speaking, here's what happens as R evaluates your code.

```
if (any (vec) != c("r", "p", "s"))  #Original: Throws warning 1
if (NA != c("r", "p", "s"))         #Next
if (c(NA, NA, NA))                  #Throws warning 2
if (NA)                             #Throws error
```

Comment: The correction you did at the beginning is something I already tried, however thank you for explaining!

Comment: The solution the other answer raises is certainly better in terms of ordering not mattering.